# Rails 3 "last" method is returning incorrect result from ActiveRecord output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've got the following code in my controller:

```
@items = Item.where(:user_id => 1).order("updated_at DESC").limit(2)
@oldest_item = @items.last
```

For some reason, and I'm guessing this has to do with my recent upgrade to Rails 3, @oldest_item is not being set to the last item in @items, but is instead being set to the last item that matches `Item.where(:user_id => 1).order("updated_at DESC")`.

So imagine there are 3 items that match, A, B, and C. @items is being set to [A, B], and then @oldest_item is being set to C.

Oddly, when I call `@items.last` from within my view, it is properly returning B.

When I paste in the two lines from my controller into the console, it also properly returns B.

Can someone explain to me what the heck is going on here?

Comment: Have you tried putting a "debugger" line in between the two lines in your controller, and running a "ruby script/console", calling your action, and digging in to see what happens? What you're doing seems right. What if you did: @oldest_item = Item.where(:user_id => 1).order("updated_at DESC").limit(2).last

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For some reason, ActiveRecord::Relation is ignoring the `limit` option.

In Rails 3, ActiveRecord doesn't actually execute your query until need to access the results. Calling `last` does this (but again, ignores the limit).

You can tell ActiveRecord to execute the query by calling `all` on your query. Then, when you run `last` on that, it'll give you the "last" record you're looking for.

```
@items = Item.where(:user_id => 1).order("updated_at DESC").limit(2)
# @items is an ActiveRecord::Relation here
@oldest_item = @items.last
# Returns "C" instead of "B". This is actually ignoring the `limit` parameter

@items = Item.where(:user_id => 1).order("updated_at DESC").limit(2).all
# @items is an Array of ActiveRecord objects here
@oldest_item = @items.last
# Returns "B"
```

This doesn't seem like expected behavior to me. I've filed a bug in the [rails issues tracker](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/371).

**Update**: @BaroqueBobcat submitted a [patch](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/451) which got accepted, so it should be fixed in the upcoming 3.1 release of Rails.

Comment: This seems like a bug in ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Rails 6 and had a similar issue. I used [reload](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-reload) on my record to reload it from the database.

```rb
account = Account.new
# => #<Account id: nil, email: nil>
account.id = 1
account.reload
# Account Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "accounts".* FROM "accounts" WHERE "accounts"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
# => #<Account id: 1, email: 'account@example.com'>
```