# Rails 4 minitest Object.last returning wrong result despite object.save passing

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, integration-testing, minitest

I have two failing tests that are currently baffling me. They are testing whether the form for a new conference is saving correctly to the database. The behavior works in the browser. These tests are testing the access to the conferences/new page through two different routes. Since 'conference' belongs to 'organization,' it is possible to add a new conference from the conferences index page (the route is the new_admin_conference_path) and also through an organization show page (where the route is new_admin_organization_conference_path(org)).

The tests:

```
  test "admin can create a conference through new_admin_conference_path" do 
    sign_in_admin
    visit new_admin_conference_path

    fill_in 'Name', :with => 'RailsConf'
    select(organizations(:valid_org).name, :from => 'conference_organization_id')

    assert_difference('Conference.count', 1) do 
      click_button 'Save'
    end

    assert_equal 'RailsConf', Conference.last.name, "field 'name' did not save to database"
    assert_equal organizations(:valid_org).id, Conference.last.organization_id, "field 'organization_id' did not save to database"
  end

  test "admin can create a conference through new_admin_organization_conference_path" do 
    sign_in_admin
    visit new_admin_organization_conference_path(organizations(:valid_org))

    fill_in 'Name', :with => 'EmberConf'

    assert_difference('Conference.count', 1) do 
      click_button 'Save'
    end

    assert_equal 'EmberConf', Conference.last.name, "field 'name' did not save to database"
    assert_equal organizations(:valid_org).id, Conference.last.organization_id, "field 'organization_id' did not save to database"
  end
```

They are failing with the messages:

```
  1) Failure:
AdminUserFlowsTest#test_admin_can_create_a_conference_through_new_admin_conference_path [/Users/wendybeth/projects/confreaks/tv3/test/integration/admin_user_flows_test.rb:141]:
field 'name' did not save to database.
Expected: "RailsConf"
  Actual: "Conference1"


  2) Failure:
AdminUserFlowsTest#test_admin_can_create_a_conference_through_new_admin_organization_conference_path [/Users/wendybeth/projects/confreaks/tv3/test/integration/admin_user_flows_test.rb:156]:
field 'name' did not save to database.
Expected: "EmberConf"
  Actual: "Conference1"

209 runs, 474 assertions, 2 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

where "Conference1" is the name of the fixture conferences(:valid_conf). However, the assert_difference('Conference.count', 1) is passing for both. I have printed Conference.count to the screen both before and after the click_button save, and it's correct (1 and then 2 respectively for both tests).

I have done save_and_open_page after click_button 'Save' for each test, and the page is properly loaded at the 'RailsConf' show page and 'EmberConf' show page, respectively, each with the appropriate 'Conference has been successfully saved' notice.

I have similar tests and functionality for Events in relation to Conferences and Videos in relation to Events - these tests all pass. My thought is that this might have something to do with the test database being weird... I am using DatabaseCleaner as such at the beginning of the test file:

```
  before :each do 
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  after :each do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean 

    if page.has_content?('Sign Out')
      click_link 'Sign Out'
    end
  end
```

For the sake of being thorough, the routes.rb file:

```
namespace :admin do
  ...

  resources :organizations do 
    resources :conferences
  end

  resources :conferences

  ...
end
```

where the '...' represent irrelevant routes.

The Conference new and create methods (using action_args):

```
  def new organization_id = nil
    @conference = Conference.new(organization_id: organization_id)
  end

  def create
    @conference = Conference.new(conference_params)

    if @conference.save
      flash[:notice] = "'#{@conference.name}' has been created."
      redirect_to admin_conference_path(@conference)
    else
      flash[:error] = "Unable to create the conference at this time."
      render action: 'new', id: @conference 
    end
  end
```

The only semi-relevant search result I've found has been here:

[Rails 3 "last" method is returning incorrect result from ActiveRecord output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864046/rails-3-last-method-is-returning-incorrect-result-from-activerecord-output)

I am using Rails 4, however. I have tried Conference.order('created_at').last with the same results, and since it was a Rails 3 ActiveRecord bug it's frustratingly not the right direction.

As suspected, when printing 'Conference.last.name' before and after each assert_difference method, it prints 'Conference1' both times despite 'RailsConf' and 'EmberConf' being successfully saved.

What the heck is going on here?

**Another note**

These tests passed when I first wrote them. It has only been since writing more code (dominantly being front-end stuff on show and index pages and having little to do with the functionality being dealt with here) that they have failed. I broke a bunch of tests by changing 'Submit' on my forms to 'Save', and while fixing that came across these two seemingly unrelated failures that are as baffling as they are frustrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assert_difference test is passing, just the comparison of data with Conference.last.{field} is failing.

Check your objects for default_scope because the record appear to be saving correctly based on passing the assert_difference.